# how to create playlist  of audio songs

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am creating a download App where i have multiple audio files in different folders inside the app,i want to create a playlist of the audio songs.i have no idea from where i should start.Currently am using the avaudio player.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
NSArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init ];
[array insertObject: [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"firstTrack" ofType:@"mp3"]] atIndex:0];
[array insertObject:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"secondTrack" ofType:@"mp3"]] atIndex:1];
[array insertObject:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"thirdTrack" ofType:@"mp3"]] atIndex:2];
[array insertObject:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"forthTrack" ofType:@"mp3"]] atIndex:3];
```

then in the player:

```
    path = [array objectAtIndex:currentTrack];
```

or use this:

```
path=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sounds" ofType:@"plist"];
dict=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];

animalaudio=[dict valueForKey:@"audio"];
  audiolist=[animalaudio objectAtIndex:currentsound];
NSLog(@"audiolist:%@",audiolist);
url=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:audiolist];
NSLog(@"url:%@",url);
 audioplayer=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
NSLog(@"audioplayer:%@",audioplayer);
 if( audioplayer == nil ){

    NSLog(@"Failed with reason: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
else{
    [audioplayer play];
}
```